# RMarkdown: Linebreak in list of authors

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, pdflatex

*RMarkdown* doesn't seem to allow line breaks when generating a PDF document via `pandoc` and *LaTeX*:

```
---
title: A short title
author: "First Author with a very, very long name; Second Author with an even longer name; Third Author with an equally long name"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book
---
```

The line breaks work in the *docx* output.

However, even if the line breaks work, it would be nice to prevent line breaks within one author.

Comment: What output do you get? Can you provide a screenshot? For me, your example produces first and second author on one line and third author on second line. Everything well spaced.

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake: When having each author on a separate line beginning with a hyphen, names are nicely displayed with a line break in PDF output, but for the *docx* output, each author will appear on a separate line.